# Why I've got "multiple-value in single-value context" error though I've received there by multiple variable at the left hand side

Tags: go

I've written 2 functions **v1GetSessionID** and **v1SessionIDforBind**.

```
/*
 * v1GetSessionID
 */
func v1GetSessionID(c *gin.Context, 
                                        app *firebase.App, 
                                        client *firestore.Client, 
                                        stripcallGetSession func() func(internalUserID string, customerID string) (sessionid string, err error)) (sessionid string, err error) {
    defer erapse.ShowErapsedTIme(time.Now())

    idToken := c.Param("idToken")
    user, err := idToken2User(app, idToken)
    if err != nil {return}
    customerID, err := user.getCustomerID()
    if err != nil {return}
    sessionid, err = stripcallGetSession()(user.getInternalID(), customerID)
    return
}

/*
 * v1SessionIDforBind
 */
func v1SessionIDforBind(c *gin.Context, app *firebase.App, client *firestore.Client) {
    defer erapse.ShowErapsedTIme(time.Now())

    var requestBody JsonPurchaseBindSessionRequest
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&requestBody); err != nil {
        okngErrorOut(c, err)
        return
    }
    stripcallGetSession := func() func(internalUserID string, customerID string) (sessionid string, err error) {
            return func(internalUserID string, customerID string)(sessionid string, err error){return stripeGetSessionIDforBind(requestBody, internalUserID, customerID)}
    }
    sessionid, err := v1GetSessionID(c, app, client, stripcallGetSession)()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        okngErrorOut(c, err)
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "SessionID": sessionid,
        })
    }
}
```

In the middle of the latter function, I've called the former as follows;

```
    sessionid, err := v1GetSessionID(c, app, client, stripcallGetSession)()
```

But go compiler indicate this as **multiple-value in single-value context**.

```
go run *.go
# command-line-arguments
./v1handler.go:332:34: multiple-value v1GetSessionID() in single-value context
```

v1GetSessionID returns 2 value of **sessionid string, err error** and I've received it by **sessionid, err**. So why I've got the error mentioned above?

go version is: go1.14.4 linux/arm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra set of parens in the call to v1GetSessionID(). You call it with 4 parameters, and it will return two values like that. But by putting the extra parenthesis after that initial call you're asking for Go to then execute the return value as if it was a function, and that's what the compiler seems to be complaining about. Simple example: https://play.golang.org/p/ZX9kp6rxA09

Just drop the second set of parentheses and it should compile:

```
sessionid, err := v1GetSessionID(c, app, client, stripcallGetSession)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and easy-to-understand answer. I didn't know what was wrong, so it was very helpful!